# Recover file overwritten with >

Tags: windows, command-line, external-hard-drive, file-recovery

I was copy/pasting some commands into CMD (Windows 7) and accidentally pasted in an entire cmd history (from the `Select All` command). This included something along the lines of

```
Y:/>database.mdb
```

Which executed and apparently wrote *Y:/ is not a recognized command* over database.mdb. I've tried Recuva, but It didn't find the file. It wasn't really *deleted*, which is why I suppose it didn't work. Is there any way to get the file back? I have a backup, but it isn't as recent as I would like.

Comment: You're right: the file wasn't deleted, it was just *overwritten*. Since the new file is smaller, part of the old content should still be saved on the disk. If you want to try to recover what's left, make sure to **stop using the drive where the file is stored right now**. Then create a full disk image, which can be used for recovery later on.

Answer (score 0):

Theese programs are really good and they will properbly work. I will recomend trying them in the order bellow.

[ZAR](http://www.z-a-recovery.com/download.htm)

[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)